# How do you scale a horizontal group inside a table

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

I have a `HorizontalGroup` in which I have two TextButtons. Now I want to scale these buttons to half their size, because their too big, but I haven't found a good way to do that, I have tried something but its not what I want.

Heres the code for setting it up

```
    weaponsButton = new TextButton("Weapons", buttonStyle);
    weaponsButton.getLabel().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    weaponsButton.pad(10f);
    statsButton = new TextButton("Stats", buttonStyle);
    statsButton.getLabel().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    statsButton.pad(10f);

    hGroup = new HorizontalGroup();
    hGroup.addActor(weaponsButton);
    hGroup.addActor(statsButton);

    table = new Table();
    table.add(hGroup);

    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.debug();

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.addActor(table);
```

`buttonStyle` is simply a `TextButtonStyle` with a `NinePatchDrawable` and a `BitmapFont`. When you draw the table it looks like this:[image: Without scaling]

adding `hGroup.setScale(0.5f);` it looks like this:

[image: With scaling]

Now `hGroup` is not aligned in the center and `.aling(Align.center)` doesn't do anything when adding the hGroup.

Calling `.width(float)` after adding `hGroup` to shrink the cell doesn't seem useful either, as I dont know the exact width of the scaled `hGroup`, it only gives the unscaled width and I find it kind of clunky to get the width and then multiply it with the scaling factor.

Even when I do that it doesn't look like I wanted it to.

```
table.add(hGroup).width(hGroup.getPrefWidth()*0.5f).height(hGroup.getPrefHeight()*0.5f);
```

looks like this:

[image: What is happening :(]

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/HorizontalGroup.html), the width of the HorizontalGroup is the sum of the preferred width of all its children (your buttons). Given that, you have a few options:

1. Call setWidth on your button actors and give them a width.
2. Skip the HorizontalGroup and just add your buttons directly to a table uniformly:

   ```
   Table table = new Table();
   table.defaults().uniformX();
   table.add(weaponsButton);
   table.add(statsButton);
   ```